# How to handle unexpected shut down of vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing VB.Net application and i wanted to block users from open another session of the program while they already has one

so i made a value in my DB that changes from Offline to Online and reverse according to the status of the log in

`Program Started = Online (In Form Load Event)`
`Program Closed = Offline (In Form Closing Event)`

The problem is : some times the program hang or windows ..... etc so the program don't change the DB value for that user from Online to Offline and this prevent him from opening the application

so how i can handle the unexpected shut down of my program to deal with this case?

Comment: Could you please add some code? Closing form code, load

Comment: what's the exact name of your program (will available in task manager)??

Comment: @Hoh Normal SQL statement to change user status from offline to online in form load and reverse in form closing

Comment: @WingedPanther CMS and yes it's available in task manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
I've created a new solution
another field should be created with name currentsession
when the user open the program it takes a number
and when UN-expected shutdown occur i made a patch to change the current status to offline and the session id to the next number
then I've created a check sub in each save button to check for the current session and if it matches the one in the database it will continue
and if not it will shutdown the program

Answer (score 3):

you could simply use the built in functionality `Single instance application` by clicking on your project and on application check `Make Single instance application` as the screen shot shows

[image: Make Single instance application]

Comment: That won't prevent a user on a different machine logging into the application which is the intention of the OP

Comment: Are you talking about lisencing?

Comment: well as Matt says it will not prevent users from opening with the same UN/PW from different computer
but your info is new for me and helped in another question :)

Comment: you can make an online file containing the ID of your app and the machine ID so that no one would be able to open a new instance with the same id.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about user session management here. If I understand you correctly, you want to stop any one user from logging in to two instances at the same time rather than there being two copies of your application open at one time (obviously with different users logged into each). If this is the case then it isn't actually that difficult to implement something very basic.

When your user logs on, perform a check to see if they already have a record in your session table. If not, then create one and issue that user with the session id. This id must then be supplied during all operations so that you can check it is valid. So far, so good.

If there is already a record in that session table then invalidate it (delete it, change the status - whatever) so that the old session id can't be used and issue a new one. That way, if your user already has a logged in copy of the app open then start another, the first one will no longer actually do anything useful (don't forget to inform users that an invalid session id is the reason why they can't do anything).

Obviously you will need to persist that session id for the life of the application, but for the love of all that is good, don't put it in a global variable: Pass it as part of the constructor to any object you instantiate which will perform any DB actions. Maybe even wrap it in a class of it's own if you need functionality and that variable or object can be private to your main class.

For example, lets say your main class is a form called frmMain which spawns a login dialog when it starts to capture username and password:

```
Public Class SessionManagerClass
    _dal As New DAL
    Private _sessionId As Int
    Private _userName As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As string)
        _sessionId = _dal.Login(UserName, Password)
    End Sub

End Class

Partial Class frmMain
    Private _session As SessionManagerClass

    Public Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim loginForm As New dlgLogin
        loginForm.ShowDialog()
        _session = New SessionManagerClass(loginForm.UserName, loginForm.Password)
        loginForm.Dispose()

    End Sub

    Public Sub btnLaunchChildForm_Click(ByVal sednder As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnLaunchChildForm.Click
        Dim frm As New frmChildForm(_session)

        frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

End Class


Partial Class frmChildForm

    _session As SessionManagerClass
    _dal As New DAL

    Public Sub New(ByVal Session As SessionManagerClass)
        _session = Session
    End Sub

    Private Sub DoSomething()
        If _dal.SaveValues(_session.SessionId, Value1, Value2, Value3) Then
            'All Good
        Else
            'Something went wrong. Maybe invalid session ID or perhaps you didn't validate your data. Whatever. Handle the problem if you can.
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is in no way working code, just an example of how you might go about it to get you started.

Comment: I know, and this solution will take care of that while still preventing a user from having two active sessions. I don't think the problem is really one of having two copies of an app open so much as one user with two active sessions logged in and how to prevent that whilst still being able to cope with an unexpected shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

You should attempt to remove the lock from the database when your application exits, but you can't stop someone going into task manager and ending the process. In this case your application does not get any notification of a shutdown and so can't write to the database.

We handle this occurrence by getting users to request an `unlock code` a secret code which allows them to clear the logged in flag. The unlock code changes each day so if they want one tomorrow they have to ask for another one.

Comment: Well, in this situation he can use this code to perform it on another PC and log in again with same UN/PW

Answer (score 0):

Review your entire approach: you can use the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class instead.

```
Dim list() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess.ProcessName)
If list.Length > 1 Then
    Application.Exit()
End If
```

Comment: I think he wants to check if the person is logged in on a different machine. Besides that you should just set the 'Single instance Application' setting to True instead of doing this.